# Reduction and collapse clauses in OMP have some confusing points

Tags: c++, openmp, reduction

Both of reduction and collapse clauses in OMP confuses me,
some points raised popped into my head

1. Why reduction doesn't work with minus? as in the limitation listed [here](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/openMP/#REDUCTION)
2. Is there any work around to achieve minus?
3. How does a unary operator work, i.e. x++ or x--? is the -- or ++ applied to each partial result? or only once at the creation of the global result? both cases are totally different.

About the collapse..
could we apply collapse on a nested loops but have some lines of code in between
for example

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    cout << "Hi"; //This is an extra line. which breaks the 2 loops.
    for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++)
    {
        cout << "*";
    }
}
```

Comment: The collapse clause can only be used on perfectly nested loops (see p62 line 5 of the OpenMP 4.5 standard : "All loops associated with the loop construct must be perfectly nested; that is, there must be no
intervening code nor any OpenMP directive between any two loops.")

Comment: Why are you interested in `for(int i=0; i<n; i++) x = a[i] - x`? There is a workaround to do this with OpenMP but I'm not sure why you would want to do this operation.

Answer (score 2):

1 & 2. For minus, what are you subtracting from? If you have two threads, do you do `result_thread_1 - result_thread_2`, or `result_thread_2 - result_thread_1`? If you have more than 2 threads, then it gets even more confusing: Do I only have one negative term and all others are positive? Is there only one positive term and others are negative? Is it a mix? Which results are which? As such, no, there is no workaround.

3. In the event of `x++` or `x--`, assuming that they are within the reduction loop, they should happen to each partial result.
4. Yes, I believe so.

Comment: There is a workaround. It might not be worth doing but that does not mean it can't be done.

Answer (score 0):

The reduction clause requires that the operation is associative and the `x = a[i] - x` operation in

```
for(int i=0; i<n; i++) x = a[i] - x;
```

is not associative.  Try a few iterations.

```
n = 0:  x = x0;
n = 1:  x = a[0] - x0;
n = 2:  x = a[1] - (a[0] - x0)
n = 3:  x = a[2] - (a[1] - (a[0] - x0))
          = a[2] - a[1] + a[0] - x0;
```

But `x = x - a[i]` does work e.g.

```
n = 3:  x = x0 - (a[2] + a[1] + a[0]);
```

However there is a workaround. The sign alternates every other term. Here is a working solution.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>

int main(void) {
    int n = 18;

    float x0 = 3;

    float a[n];
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) a[i] = i;
    float x = x0;
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) x = a[i] - x; printf("%f\n", x);

    int sign = n%2== 0 ? -1 : 1 ;
    float s = -sign*x0;
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        float sp = 0;
        int signp = 1;
        #pragma omp for schedule(static)
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++) sp += signp*a[i], signp *= -1;

        #pragma omp for schedule(static) ordered
        for(int i=0; i<omp_get_num_threads(); i++)
            #pragma omp ordered
            s += sign*sp, sign *= signp;
    }
    printf("%f\n", s);
}
```

---

Here is a simpler version which uses the `reduction` clause.  The thing to notice is that the odd terms are all one sign and the even terms another.  So if we do the reduction two terms at a time the sign does not change and the operation is associative.

```
x = x0;
for(int i=0; i<n; i++) x = a[i] - x
```

can be reduced in parallel like this.

```
x = n%2 ? a[0] - x0 : x0;
#pragma omp parallel for reduction (+:x)
for(int i=0; i<n/2; i++) x += a[2*i+1+n%2] - a[2*i+n%2];
```